# increase size of form widgets

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, widget

This question is so basic, it's kind of embarrassing, but here goes...

This is for Symfony 1.4 - I am trying to modify some auto-generated forms in a Symfony 1.4 app.  The problem is, the widgets are rendered too small to display all of the text in the field. For example, in the database table, I have a field of type varchar(50), but the widget only displays 20 characters. I have tried to increase the size in the _form class e.g.

```
<td colspan="4"> <?php echo $form['email'] ?></td>
```

but this doesn't appear to have any effect.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in differents ways.

- Associate a class/style in the template:

You give some attributes to the render.

```
<?php echo $form->render(array('email' => array('class' => 'email'))) ?>
<?php echo $form['email']->renderRow(array('class' => 'email')) ?>

// Both generate HTML
<input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" id="contact_email" class="email" />
```

- Associate the class/style in the widget:

You give some attributes to the widget.

```
$this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('class' => 'email'));
```

Comment: Sorry again if this is obvious, but I'm assuming I then dictate the size of the widget in a CSS file.

Comment: Exactly, by adding a class or directly the style, you can set the size of the widget (ie: input, textarea, select, etc ...) using css.